# Problems installing Audio Unit components on High Sierra

Tags: audio, high-sierra, logic

```
Apple Mac Pro (early 2009) Firmware 4.1 -> 5.1
macOS 10.13.0 High Sierra
Logic Pro X 10.3.2
```

Hello, I upgraded my Apple Mac Pro to High Sierra last week. This may have been a slightly rash move for I find that whenever I have attempted to install an AU based plugin intended for use with Logic Pro X, I am having difficulties in getting Logic Pro to recognise the new plug-in.

I know that deleting `/Users/carlca/Library/Caches/AudioUnitCache/com.apple.audiounits.cache` will force Logic Pro X to run AuScan, and I have also discovered that rebooting the machine just prior to installing a new plug-in sometimes helps, but it's nowhere near 100% reliable and it's a pain in the derriere.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? Or has someone found a reliable way to install AU based plugins for Logic Pro X under macOS High Sierra?

I'm hoping I don't need to wait for macOS High Sierra and/or Logic Pro X to be updated.

Comment: Hopefully someone here can give you an answer, but another option is to contact Apple. They will assist you, especially since it's related to macOS High Sierra. If you find they have no solution, then ensure you submit feedback to Apple, both for [macOS](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html) and [Logic Pro](https://www.apple.com/feedback/logic-pro.html). Finally, if you resolve your issue, please come back and answer your own question here as it will no doubt help other users! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I have made progress with my setup. The trick seems to be to be disciplined enough to carry out the installations, then deleting /Users/[USER]/Library/Caches/AudioUnitCache/com.apple.audiounits.cache, then rebooting, before finally opening Logic Pro X again, at which point it should rescan all the new plugins. It's a fiddly procedure but it seems to work!

Answer (score 2):

Good news, I think! I've just installed the newly released 10.13.1 High Sierra update. I then high-tailed it over to KVRAudio and downloaded an AU plugin (Sprike, since you ask - it's pretty good!). I was able to install it and then run Logic Pro X without any deleting of files or rebooting malarky. It just worked.